# Most Pyhthonic way to convert element of list get with re

Tags: python, regex, list, integer

I am using regex to extract some numbers out of a string (lp). I know that the list that I will get out of it will contain only 2 elements. I also know they will both be integers.

Therefore I would like to write this with just one line of code.

```
home,away = re.findall(r'\d+',lp)
home,away = int(home),int(away)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', lp))` ?

Comment: Thanks. I will read a bit more about map then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
home, away = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', lp))
```

Another idea is to use list comprehension :

```
home, away = [int(e) for e in re.findall(r'\d+', lp)]
```

---

Little trick about managing types when you have a static result length :

```
expected_types = [int, int, str]
elements = ['1', '2', 'toto']

result = [_type(e) for _type, e in zip(exected_types, elements]
# Returns : [1, 2, 'toto']
```

Comment: Merci. Tu viens d ajouter le soleil de Pau dans mon code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

`home, away = [ int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', lp) ]`

Edit: FunkySayu you are faster ...